# PHP escape JSON string saved in a var

Tags: php, json, file-upload

So I have some JSON string that I write to a file, and parse it afterwards, for an export/import tool the problem is on import when I try to parse the file using json_decode it dies because of the caracter escaping.

Here I have an example so you can understand better:

[image]

When I write the content I do some basic file_put and json_encode

eg:

```
$current .= "\n\n\n".'$pagzDynamicPages = \''.json_encode($pagzDynamicPagesData).'\';';
```

So is there a way to escape this type of strings?

Comment: Maybe you could use; mysql_real_escape_string or the mysqli version of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$current .= "\n\n\n".
    '$pagzDynamicPages = '.
    var_export(json_encode($pagzDynamicPagesData), TRUE).
    ';';
```

The function [`var_export()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) produces a valid PHP expression for the provided data structure.

Comment: I want to offer the file to be available for download...so var_export won't work in this case... I tried... and it displays the content instead of offering it for download

Comment: Check its [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php). If you pass `TRUE` as the second parameter it won't output anything but **return** the PHP code it produces.

Comment: I misplaced a closing parenthesis on the original version of the code. Fixed now and formatted to code to be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape it properly. Best way probably is heredoc: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the `JSON` with `str_replace`:

```
$pagzDynamicPagesData = str_replace("'", "\'", $pagzDynamicPages);
```